# Как сделать асинхронный Websocket в Angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Всем привет. Имеется данный код:

```
.run(["$rootScope", "$cacheFactory", "$websocket", function($rootScope, $cacheFactory, $websocket) {
            $rootScope.cache = $cacheFactory('PJ');
            $rootScope.ws = $websocket('ws://localhost');
        }])
        .controller('profileInfo', ['$scope', '$http', '$cookieStore', 'Websocket', '$rootScope', function($scope, $http, $cookieStore, Websocket, $rootScope) {
            var subject = 'user';
            var param = '"user": {"login": "'+ $cookieStore.get('uname') +'"}';
            var method = 'get_info';

            Websocket.get(param, subject, method)
                .then(function(data) {
                       alert(data);
                });

            var subject = 'user';
            var param = '"user": {"login": "'+ $cookieStore.get('uname') +'"}';
            var method = 'get_projects';
            $scope.keys = {};

            Websocket.get(param, subject, method)
                .then(function(data) {
                     alert(data);
                });

        }])
        .factory('Websocket',['$rootScope', '$q', function($rootScope, $q) {

            function randomId(){
                var s ='', abd ='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789', aL = abd.length;
                while(s.length < '40')
                    s += abd[Math.random() * aL|0];
                return s;
            }

            var get = function(param, subject, method) {
                var id = randomId();
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                $rootScope.ws.send('{"id": "' + id + '", "type": "request", "version": "v.2.0", "method": "' + method + '", "subject": "' + subject + '", "parameters": {' + param + '}}');
                $rootScope.ws.onMessage(function (message) {
                    deferred.resolve(message.data);
                });

                return deferred.promise;
            }

            return {
                get: get
            };
        }]);
```

Но результат первого запроса, грузится во 2-ом запросе.
Т.е ответные данные из этого блока:

```
var subject = 'user';
            var param = '"user": {"login": "'+ $cookieStore.get('uname') +'"}';
            var method = 'get_info';

            Websocket.get(param, subject, method)
                .then(function(data) {
                     alert(data);
                });
```

Попадают в этот блок:

```
var subject = 'user';
            var param = '"user": {"login": "'+ $cookieStore.get('uname') +'"}';
            var method = 'get_projects';
            $scope.keys = {};

            Websocket.get(param, subject, method)
                .then(function(data) {
                      alert(data);
                });
```

Comment: ну так `ws` же один используется